# как указать сразу на все элементы из списка

Tags: python-3.x, список

```
deck_factor_cost = ["1 red", "1 black", "1 red", "1 black", "2 red", "2 red", "2 black", "2 black", "3 red",
                    "3 black", "3 red", "3 black", "4 red", "4 black", "4 red", "4 black", "5 red", "5 black",
                    "5 red", "5 black", "6 red", "6 black", "6 red", "6 black", "7 red", "7 black", "7 red", "7 black",
                    "8 red", "8 black", "8 red", "8 black", "9 red", "9 black", "9 red", "9 black","10 red", "10 black","10 red", "10 black",]

deck_factor_effect = ["A red", "A black", "B red", "B black", "J red", "J black", "H red", "H black", "Q red", "Q black",
                      "A red", "A black", "B red", "B black", "J red", "J black", "H red", "H black", "Q red", "Q black"]

bank_1 = []
bank_2 = []
deck_1 = []
deck_2 = []
fund_1 = []
fund_2 = []

score = True

from random import choice
print("банк 1-ого игрока")
bank_cost1 = 0
for i in range(5):
    num_card = choice(deck_factor_cost)
    deck_factor_cost.remove(num_card)
    bank_1.append(num_card)
    bank_cost1 += int(num_card[0])

print(bank_1)


print("")
print("банк 2-ого игрока")
bank_cost2 = 0
for i in range(5):
    num_card = choice(deck_factor_cost)
    deck_factor_cost.remove(num_card)
    bank_2.append(num_card)
    bank_cost2 += int(num_card[0])

print(bank_2)


print("")
print("карты 1-ого игрока")
for i in range(6):
    num_card = choice(deck_factor_cost)
    deck_factor_cost.remove(num_card)
    deck_1.append(num_card)

print(deck_1)


print("")
print("карты 2-ого игрока")
for i in range(6):
    num_card = choice(deck_factor_cost)
    deck_factor_cost.remove(num_card)
    deck_2.append(num_card)

print(deck_2)


print("")
print("резерв 1-ого игрока")
for i in range(2):
    num_card = choice(deck_factor_cost)
    deck_factor_cost.remove(num_card)
    fund_1.append(num_card)

print(fund_1)


print("")
print("резерв 2-ого игрока")
for i in range(2):
    num_card = choice(deck_factor_cost)
    deck_factor_cost.remove(num_card)
    fund_2.append(num_card)

print(fund_2)


print("")
print("Стоимость банка 1-ого игрока ", bank_cost1)
print("Стоимость банка 2-ого игрока ", bank_cost2)
if bank_cost1 < bank_cost2:
    print("начинает 1-ый игрок")
    turn = True
else:
    print("начинает 2-ой игрок")
    turn = None


print("Ваш ход                     ", "выберите 4 карты")
force = []
inter = input()

if inter != deck_1
```

> **здесь возникает трудность. Можно ли отправить на проверку все элементы из списка deck_1?**

Comment: Ну вообще python умеет сравнивать списки по значению. Или о какой проверке вы говорите?

Comment: `if int(inter) not in deck_1:`?